# Could not find module ember-metal/streams/stream

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I got this error after upgrade. Running `ember init` couple of times. It didn't fix it. Thinking one of my add-on is causing this because it is not updated to certain new Ember paradigm. The page loads up, but it stops at some point - seemingly hitting the route.

How can I find which add-on causes this? This is what I got in my browser console. Ember console had nothing happened.

```
Uncaught Error
: Could not find module ember-metal/streams/stream ember.debug.js
:58missingModule ember.debug.js
:58internalRequire ember.debug.js
:80requireModule ember.debug.js
:44(anonymous function) stream.js
:11Module.exports loader.js
:123Module.reify loader.js
:144Module.exports loader.js
:121Module.reify loader.js
:144Module.exports loader.js
:121requireModule loader.js
:23(anonymous function) index.js
:18exports.default index.js
:15(anonymous function) app.js
:13Module.exports loader.js
:123requireModule loader.js
:23(anonymous function)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that one of your project dependencies requires updating. The most likely culprit is `liquid-fire`.

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer is the right answer. I found the package that needs updating. It's ember-i18n. After bumping from 4.2.0 -> 4.3.0. Too much time have wasted on this so I am really not happy at all except want to tell you that you were very kind to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The update of "ember-i18n" package solves this issue.
In my case, it was from "4.2.2" to "5.3.1"

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because of 'npm link'. I had upgraded my Ember to 2.7 and had not linked the shared project which was linked to my project and that was causing this error. Once you upgrade your ember version and you have some dependent project (for my case there was a shared project which had all the common controllers, templates and models between multiple application) do following:

1. Upgrade your current project
2. rm -rf node_modules bower tmp
3. npm link
4. npn install; bower install
5. npm start

and this should solve this error in case above methods don't work and you have a shared app.